# how to use pipenv to run file in current folder

Tags: python, path, pipenv, virtual-environment

Using `pipenv` to create a virtual environment in a folder. 
However, the environment seems to be in the path:

> /Users/....../.local/share/virtualenvs/......

And when I run the command `pipenv run python train.py`, I get the error:

> can't open file 'train.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

How to run a file in the folder where I created the virtual environment?

Comment: you can verify the location of your environment using the command:
   `pipenv --where`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to be in the same directory of the file you want to run then use:
`pipenv run python train.py`

Note:

> You may be at the project main directory while the file you need to run is inside a directory inside your project directory
>
> If you use django to create your project, it will create two folders inside each other with the same name so as a best practice change the top directory name to 'yourname-project' then inside the directory 'yourname' run the `pipenv run python train.py` command

Answer (score 2):

You can activate the virtual environment then run the file

```
    pipenv shell
    python train.py
```